# Regex Java when we have specific text upto a pattern

Tags: java, regex

```
As i haven't much worked on regex, can someone help me out in getting the answer for below thing:
```

(1)I want to remove a text say **Element**

(2)It may of may not followed by delimiter say **pipe(||)**

```
I tried below thing, but it is not working in the way i want:

String str = "String:abc||Element:abc||Value:abc"; // Sample text 1
String str1 = "String:abc||Element:abc"; // Sample text 2
System.out.println(str.replaceFirst("Element.*\\||", ""));
System.out.println(str1.replaceFirst("Element.*\\||", ""));

Required output in above cases:

String:abc||Value:abc //for the first case
String:abc //for the second case
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you can decide to give another value to the original pattern which is `Element` in this case, you can use `Pattern.quote` to escape it as below:

```
String str = "String:abc||Element:abc||Value:abc"; // Sample text 1
String str1 = "String:abc||Element:abc"; // Sample text 2
String originalPattern = "Element";
String pattern = String.format("\\|{2}%s[^\\|]+", Pattern.quote(originalPattern));
System.out.println(str.replaceFirst(pattern, ""));
System.out.println(str1.replaceFirst(pattern, ""));
```

Your patter is then generic and its value is `String.format("\\|{2}%s[^\\|]+", Pattern.quote(originalPattern))`
**Output:**

```
String:abc||Value:abc
String:abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the escape wrong. It should be:

```
Element(.*?\|\||.*$)
```

Put the escape on each pipe, and use `?` for non greedy Regex so you only replace just enough string, not everything.

Comment: This must not be the correct answer. It is not even compiling. Other than that this isn't replacing anything from the given text.. :(

Comment: One more thing, Pipe may or may not be there in the text. As in if the Element is at the end then we don't have Pipe after that text. But if Element is in the middle then only Pipe will be there.

Comment: You should use a Regex function, not a string replace. My Regex is right, but you don't use the right function

Comment: I have improved the code for optional Pipe appearance, but you still need to change your function. Sorry I don't use Java. I am only good in Regex

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "String:abc||Element:abc||Value:abc";
text = text.replaceAll("\\belement\\b", "");
```

you might need to use replace all this will replace all element from your string here i am using  `'\b'` word boundary in `java regular expression` in between the words

Comment: Already tried this. But not working as this is just replacing the Element. We wanted to replace Element:<any other text>. Also Pipe may or may not be there after the Element tag

Comment: this is working and how come this can't replace any other text if this is capable of replacing element you just need to use it correctly.

Comment: its okay if you dont have a pipe or whatever just try this `text =text.replaceAll("\\belement\\b", "word to replace");`